# What statistic does CA Wily Introscope's MetricsDataService::getMetricData return?

Tags: python, soap, introscope

I'm calling getMetricData using Python's suds SOAP client, I request the smallest time interval possible (15 seconds) for a CPU metric and a time period that I have also exported to CSV from Introscope Workstation.

The exported values are the same as in Workstation and look like this:

```
Value Count  Value Type   Integer Value   Integer Min   Integer Max
6            Long         18796           8906          35787
```

I'm assuming that "Integer Value" is an average, either the median or the mean of the 6 samples captured for this time period.

I use something like this to extract the same time period using the API:

```
WILY_WSDL = 'http://%s:%s/introscope-web-services/services/MetricsDataService?wsdl' % (WILY_SERVER, WILY_IP)
SoapClient = Client(WILY_WSDL, username=WILY_USER, password=WILY_PASS)
print SoapClient.service.getMetricData(agentName, metricName, startTime, endTime, '15')
```

The `metricValue` for the time slice I'm interested in has a value of 17669, which isn't the same value as the one exported by the client.

From what I can see the documentation doesn't say what function generates these statistics or what their difference is.

Are they the mean, the median, mode, a random sample or something else entirely?

Comment: any luck with this? I am trying to do the same. I get agnetName not defined error.

Comment: yes, my WSDL client worked, but no, I never got an answer to this question. You'll need to provide your own agentName, metricName and so on. Unfortunately I no longer have the code for this, I wrote it for a client